# Android: strange behavior of Soft Keyboard with EditText and ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm going crazy!!! Please help me. Ths is the problem:

If i have an Activity with an `EditText` and a `ListView` the Soft Keyboard is shown when the Activity comes visible.

If i have remove the `ListView` the Soft Keyboard is no more shown.

I want to perform the first situation (Activity with an `EditText` and a `ListView`) with the second behavior (Soft Keyboard hidden).
I have try to hide the Soft Keyboard in `onResume()` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) but it not works.

Please suggest me a workaround to hide the Soft Keyboard. Thank you so much.

P.s. Sorry for my English ;) Hope the problem is clear.

Comment: why dont you hide it in onCreate?

Comment: put this in onCreate getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onCreate` of your activity you will want to add the following:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```